# Source Model not set when adding customer attribute - Magento 2.2.1

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-attribute

I have looked over a few tutorials on how to add a customer attribute to the customer edit page within admin.

- http://www.extensions.sashas.org/blog/magento-2-make-customer-attribute.html
- [Magento 2: How to create a customer custom attribute?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88245/magento-2-how-to-create-a-customer-custom-attribute)
- [How to add dropdown attribute to custom module in magento 2.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153532/how-to-add-dropdown-attribute-to-custom-module-in-magento-2-0/153539)

This however does not seem to be working completely for me. I added the below to my **InstallData.php** file:

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {

    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'cp_permissions', [
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' => 'Account Type',
        'input' => 'select',
        'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
        'required' => false,
        'visible' => true,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'sort_order' => 101,
        'position' => 101,
        'system' => 0,
        'option' =>
            array (
                'values' =>
                    array (
                        0 => 'Master',
                        1 => 'Branch'
                    ),
            ),
    ]);

    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'cp_permissions')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
        ]);

    $attribute->save();

    }
}
```

And run `setup:upgrade` to install the plugin.

I compared my attribute to the gender attribute. Main issues seems to be that, the **source model** wasn't being set and need to work out how to make sure this is set. When i set the source manually it shows up fine however.

Answer (score 0):

### Setting the Source Model Correctly

Studying the **/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Setup/customerSetup.php** file from the core i could see that source was being set differently to other answers on stack exchange:

```
 'source' => \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\Website::class,
 'backend' => \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Attribute\Backend\Website::class,
```

I changed the setup data script to match and this added the source to the database however attribute still didn't show. Comparing the **gender** attribute again i could see that **user_defined** was set to 0 rather than 1. Setting this seemed to be the final step to kick the attribute into action.

### Final addAttribute Method:

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'cp_permissions', [
        'type' => 'static',
        'label' => 'Account Type',
        'input' => 'select',
        'source' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table::class,
        'required' => false,
        'visible' => true,
        'user_defined' => false,
        'sort_order' => 101,
        'position' => 101,
        'system' => 0,
        'adminhtml_only' => 1,
        'option' =>
            array (
                'values' =>
                    array (
                        0 => 'Master',
                        1 => 'Branch'
                    ),
            ),
    ]);
```