# Customer dropdown values in phtml file

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-attribute

I created the one custom dropdown attribute in customer side. I need to show in frontend phtml all the dropdown list because a user can select any one of this. can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create a customer attribute of dropdown type using the procedure shown here:
[How to add dropdown attribute to custom module in magento 2.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153532/how-to-add-dropdown-attribute-to-custom-module-in-magento-2-0/153539)

After this, if you are can create a dropdown to the phtml where you want to show the dropdown with the values being shown here.

If you use proper values for the index **used_in_forms**, then it will be automatically shown on those forms.
For more details, refer:
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2018/04/17/add-customer-attributes-programmatically-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this

```
$yourAttribute=$this->eavConfig->getAttribute('customer','YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE');

if($yourAttribute->getSource()){
    $options = $yourAttribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
}
```